# dvm Heap Source Startup After Zygote

Tags: android-ndk

When running my app I occasionally receive a `"Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)"`. Using `ndk-stack` on the related logs it gives the following output:

**Crash dump: Build fingerprint:**

```
'samsung/espresso10wifibby/espresso10wifi:4.0.4/IMM76D/P5113UEBLH3:user/release-keys'
pid: 32589, tid: 32592  >>> packagename <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
Stack frame #00  pc 0007c108  /system/lib/libdvm.so: Unable to open symbol file F:/project-path/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libdvm.so. Error (3): No such process
```

On `doin addr2line on 7c108 in libdvm.so` I get:

```
dvmHeapSourceStartupAfterZygote()
??:0
```

`dvmHeapSourceStartupAfterZygote()` basically creates a new heap for post-zygote allocations if Heap Source was created in zygote mode.

Now I know the `libdvm.so` is not the problem. But it should be somewhere in my code. And I cannot share my code. So it would be great if I can get some pointers as to where in my code I need to look into to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Here is the entire fatal signal crash dump:

```
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/espresso10wifibby/espresso10wifi:4.0.4/IMM76D/P5113UEBLH3:user/release-keys'
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97): pid: 26946, tid: 26950  >>> package-name <<<
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  r0 ffffffff  r1 10100000  r2 00000004  r3 0083d580
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  r4 00000000  r5 10100000  r6 4007f4f4  r7 00000000
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  r8 100ffe98  r9 4007f4f4  10 409569d8  fp 409180e1
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  ip 4005d979  sp 100ffe58  lr 4005d971  pc 40918108  cpsr 00000030
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d0  6573756170202c4b  d1  0000111100a44531
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d2  0000000010000034  d3  0008104100000036
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d4  0000000410000000  d5  0000104000102000
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d6  00b31fe000000000  d7  0000005b4e805607
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d16 0000000000000000  d17 3ff0000000000000
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d18 4146605000000000  d19 bfb1be5a93a83e1d
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d20 3f1155e54e7e8408  d21 bebbbc6c1a570a20
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d22 3ff0000000000000  d23 3fede16b9c24a98f
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d24 3e66376972bea4d0  d25 3fc39a09d078c69f
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
06-26 12:12:20.546: I/DEBUG(97):  scr 80000012
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):          #00  pc 0007c108  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):          #01  lr 4005d971  /system/lib/libc.so
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): code around pc:
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): 409180e8 657ef421 f025321f f422051f f020607e  !.~e.2%...".~` .
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): 409180f8 42a8001f 1a2dd207 46292204 e982f7a2  ...B..-..")F....
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): 40918108 195d6823 bd706025 4ff0e92d bf944290  #h].%`p.-..O.B..
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): 40918118 0800f04f 0801f04f bf88428a 0801f048  O...O....B..H...
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): 40918128 4683b085 4691468a 0f00f1b8 4963d00c  ...F.F.F......cI
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): code around lr:
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): 4005d950 f240b507 9300736c 33fff04f 466b9301  ..@.ls..O..3..kF
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): 4005d960 fd80f7ff bf00bd0e 4604b510 fc78f7ec  ...........F..x.
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): 4005d970 f04f6004 bd1030ff 0ffff110 db02b510  .`O..0..........
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): 4005d980 f7ff4240 bd10fff1 48214603 4478b5f0  @B.......F!H..xD
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): 4005d990 b0976800 68022150 4620ac01 92154e1d  .h..P!.h.. F.N..
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): stack:
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe18  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe1c  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe20  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe24  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe28  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe2c  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe30  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe34  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe38  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe3c  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe40  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe44  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe48  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe4c  4005d987  /system/lib/libc.so
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe50  df0027ad  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe54  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97): #00 100ffe58  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe5c  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe60  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe64  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe68  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe6c  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe70  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe74  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe78  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe7c  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe80  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.078: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe84  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.085: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe88  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.085: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe8c  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.085: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe90  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.085: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe94  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.085: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe98  00000000  
06-26 12:12:21.085: I/DEBUG(97):     100ffe9c  00000000
```

Comment: Is there any more to the stack frame?  My guess would be that something went wrong with addr2line and you've got the wrong symbol, unless some bit of code is making wayward method calls.  Where'd you get the symbolized version of libdvm.so for samsung/espresso10wifibby/espresso10wifi:4.0.4/IMM76D/P5113UEBLH3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this segmentation fault. It was due to a malloc not being not being allocated with the correct number of bytes.